# How add sorting to spring data elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I m writing an api using elasticsearch spring data and I want to add ordering.I cant find a resolve in google. So I write here to ask you guys how I can do that. If you will need more code please tell me what u need and I try to add more code.

My code looks like:

AuctionQueryController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auctions/search", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private List<Auction> search(
            @RequestParam(value = "categoryId", required = false) Long categoryId,
            @RequestParam(value = "treeCategoryId", required = false) Long treeCategoryId,
            @RequestParam(value = "currency", required = false) String currency,
            @RequestParam(value = "priceFrom", required = false) Long priceFrom,
            @RequestParam(value = "priceTo", required = false) Long priceTo,
            @RequestParam(value = "startDateFrom", required = false) Long startDateFrom,
            @RequestParam(value = "startDateTo", required = false) Long startDateTo,
            @RequestParam(value = "endDateFrom", required = false) Long endDateFrom,
            @RequestParam(value = "endDateTo", required = false) Long endDateTo,
            @RequestParam(value = "title", required = false) String title,
            @RequestParam(value = "uid", required = false) Long uid,
            Pageable pageable) {

        final AuctionIndexSearchParams searchParams = AuctionIndexSearchParams.builder()
                .categoryId(categoryId)
                .treeCategoryId(treeCategoryId)
                .currency(currency)
                .priceFrom(priceFrom)
                .priceTo(priceTo)
                .startDateFrom(startDateFrom)
                .startDateTo(startDateTo)
                .endDateFrom(endDateFrom)
                .endDateTo(endDateTo)
                .title(title)
                .uid(uid)
                .build();

        return auctionService.searchByIndexParams(searchParams, pageable);
    }
```

AuctionService.java

```
public List<Auction> searchByIndexParams(AuctionIndexSearchParams searchParams, Pageable pageable) {
        final List<FilterBuilder> filters = Lists.newArrayList();
        final NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery());

        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("cat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCurrency()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("curr", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTreeCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("tcat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getUid()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("uid", v))));

       final BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTitle()).isPresent()) {
            boolQueryBuilder.should(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getTitle()).analyzeWildcard(true).field("title"));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).isPresent()
                && Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("start_date").from(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getStartDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).isPresent()
                && Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("end_date").from(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getEndDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).isPresent()
                && Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("price").from(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).to(searchParams.getPriceTo()));
        }

        searchQuery.withPageable(pageable);
        searchQuery.withQuery(boolQueryBuilder);
        FilterBuilder[] filterArr = new FilterBuilder[filters.size()];
        filterArr = filters.toArray(filterArr);
        searchQuery.withFilter(andFilter(filterArr));

        final FacetedPage<AuctionIndex> search = auctionIndexRepository.search(searchQuery.build());

        return search.map(index ->
                        auctionRepository.findAuctionById(Long.valueOf(index.getId()))
        ).getContent();
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `SortBuilders` for this.

```
        searchQuery.withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("fieldName").order(SortOrder.DESC))
```

This will sort your result on the basis of `fieldName` passed.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok and how add to this order of field?

Comment: Edited as per your requirement

Comment: how to order by multiple fields?